# javascript can't take off first letter of string

Tags: javascript, replace, substring

I have a js function that once finished will compute basic algebra equations. For some reason, It won't let me replace the first character of a string in an array. I've used it before in this function, but it won't work now. I've tried using the .replace() as well as .substring().

These are the following codes I've tried:

```
// this is what i've been testing it on
// $problem[o][j] = +5
var assi = $problem[0][j].charAt(0); // Get the first character, to replace to opposite sign
switch (assi){
  case "+":
    console.log($problem[0][j]);
    $problem[0][j].replace("+","-");
    console.log($problem[0][j]);
    break;
}
```

The above outputs to the console:

```
> +5
> +5
```

Next code I tried:

```
// Second code i tried with $problem[0][j] remaining the same
switch(assi){
  case "+":
    console.log($problem[0][j]);
    $problem[0][j].substring(1);
    $problem[0][j] = "-" + $problem[0][j];
    console.log($problem[0][j]);
    break;
}
```

This outputs to the console:

```
> +5
> -+5
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable - the contents of a certain string cannot be changed. You need to create a new string with the replacements. You can assign this new string to the old variable to make it "look like" modification.

```
var a = "asd";
var b = a.replace(/^./, "b"); //replace first character with b
console.log(b); //"bsd";
```

Reassigning:

```
var a = "asd";
a = a.replace(/^./, "b"); //replace first character with b
console.log(a); //"bsd";
```

---

If you want to flip the sign of a number, it's probably easier to just multiply with -1.

Comment: Also note that `a = a.replace(...)` creates a *new string object* and *assigns it to `a`*. So if you need to *modify* `a`, you can do: `a = a.replace(...)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace the actual string with the new one

```
$problem[0][j] = $problem[0][j].replace("+","-");
```

Answer (score 1):

`.replace()` doesn't make the change in the string, it just **returns** a new string with those changes made.

//This does nothing

```
problem[0][j].replace("+","-");
```

//This saves the replaced string

```
problem[0][j] = problem[0][j].replace("+","-");
```

Comment: Simple mistake when coding for 12 hours straight. >.>